# Unit tests, Mock objects in Debug and in Run modes

Tags: java, junit

I'm developing unit test.
**If I start test in Run mode, the run is failed with message:**

```
This exception may occur if matchers are combined with raw values: 
   //incorrect:
   someMethod(anyObject(), "raw String");
When using matchers, all arguments have to be provided by matchers.
For example:
   //correct:
   someMethod(anyObject(), eq("String by matcher"));
For more info see javadoc for Matchers class.
```

**If I run the test in Debug mode with the breakpoint on String tableName = table.getTableName() the test is passing well. The stop occurs on the breakpoint.**

```
@Test
void myTest() {
    Table table = mock(Table.class);
    when(table.getTableName()).thenReturn("mytableName")
    SQLService service = new SQLService(table);
    service.select();
}

class SQLService {
    private final Table table;
    SQLService(Table table) {
         this.table = table;
    }

    void select() {
        String tableName = table.getTableName(); // <---- issue here, breakpoint is set on this line
        ........    
    }
}
```

Comment: I use `org.mockito.Mockito` works well

Answer (score 1):

This issue is caused by mixing matchers with raw values. If you use matchers then you need to use matchers for all arguments.

Try and use the .eq() matcher, with your code it is something like this:

```
when(Mockito.eq(table.getTableName())).thenReturn("mytableName");
```

Comment: Do you know why the tests passed in Debug mode + breakpoint, and don't pass in Run mode ?

Comment: "The stop occurs on the breakpoint" - I assumed this meant that the test stops? 
Either way you'll need the test to pass without debug mode - have you tried using .eq()?

Comment: Yes, I tried use it, I got: **Examples of correct usage of argument matchers:
    when(mock.get(anyInt())).thenReturn(null);
    doThrow(new RuntimeException()).when(mock).someVoidMethod(anyObject());
    verify(mock).someMethod(contains("foo"))**

Comment: PC: the test stopped on debugpoint, and I pressed run (continue execution).